# Initialization of Performance Counters in .net are very slow

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, performancecounter

I am currently having two `PerformanceCounter`s that are creating issues when my Windows Forms application is to be started.

The `PerformanceCounter`s are created in the designer class of a `UserControl` that is initiated when the application starts. The counters, called `performanceCounterMemory` and `performanceCounterProTime`, are created to be able to give the user a real time feedback of the currently used RAM memory and process time (percentage). They are created with the following lines in the designer class

```
    this.performanceCounterMemory = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter();
    this.performanceCounterProTime = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter();

    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.performanceCounterMemory)).BeginInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.performanceCounterProTime)).BeginInit();

    this.performanceCounterMemory.CategoryName = "Memory";
    this.performanceCounterMemory.CounterName = "% used dedicated byte";
        
    this.performanceCounterProTime.CategoryName = "Processor";
    this.performanceCounterProTime.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    this.performanceCounterProTime.InstanceName = "_Total";

    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.performanceCounterMemory)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.performanceCounterProTime)).EndInit();
```

For reasons unknown the calls to the last two lines, the `EndInit()` calls, for both counters are really slow (10+ seconds) making the application very slow to start.

Why is this? What is the purpose of the `EndInit` calls and is it possible to make it faster?

To be able to use the counters the following two references are added by the lines

```
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
using System.Management;
```

The machine processor is: **Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz**

Comment: I believe EndInit basically acts like `Wait`, waiting for the initialization to be done. It is slow. You can move this to another thread or wait to call EndInit until you are ready to read the counters

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out. Any idea why performance counters take so much longer to init compared to other controls such as `DataGridView`?

Comment: I really don't but I've noticed it. I know they have to run for a period of time to get meaningful data (sampling CPU usage over time).

Comment: For what it's worth, any user can already see the resources being used by any program at any time by using Task Manager.

Comment: Indeed, however I want the application to be able to detect if/when the values of either counters reaches over a certain value during a time period.

Comment: Simply don't use PerformanceCounter Components, run [PerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter) class objects and return their values from a ThreadPool Thread. Read the notes about multi-threading.

Answer (score 1):

```
long memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
```

You can use the following function (the true parameter tells GC to build first)
This is for RAM, I don't really understand, maybe it will help)